# Django Aggregation with a Model that has two foreign key fields pointing to same foreign Model?

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
from reviews.models import *
from django.db.models import Count

class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('core.User')
    status = models.CharField(default='5 star', max_length=100)
    reviewed_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, blank=True, null=True)
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey('core.User', related_name='reviewer', null=True)
```

I can list the top 5 Review.user's with the most Reviews like this:

```
for u in User.objects.annotate(num_reviews=Count('review')).order_by('-num_reviews')[:5]:
...    print u.login, u.num_reviews, u.title
...    
bobby 395 Manager
paul 377 Project Manager
micheal 283 Program Manager
kim 252 Engineer
goober 210 Engineer
```

But how can I list the top 5 Review.reviewers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it's

```
for u in User.objects.annotate(num_reviews=Count('reviewer')).order_by('-num_reviews')[:5]:
...    print u.login, u.num_reviews, u.title
```

I think the problem here is with related name `reviewer` which confused you. It should have  named like `reviewed_reviews` which is more clear and understandable.

Comment: That works! But why does `Count('review')` give me the results it does?

Comment: @RedCricket that's django's work. It named your related name by itself like ```review``` in aggregation and prefetching queries if you did not name it manually. To prevent it I always give related names to FK's.

Comment: Btw, related query names in ```User```'s instance in your case will be like ```user.review_set.all()``` as an author and ```user.reviewer.all()``` as an reviewer. Which is also confusing